# CombineLatest with a completed Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following observables:

```
Observable<Void> obsOne = thisOne.callsOnComplete();
Observable<User> obsTwo = thisOne.callsOnNextThenOnComplete();
```

Now, I'd like to execute both simultaneously and then grab the result of `obsTwo` and do a third action. The problem is that `zip`/`combineLatest` don't seem to work since `obsOne` doesn't emit any items. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to materialize first observable `Observable<Void> obsOne = thisOne.callsOnComplete().materialize();` - in that case it will emit at least one notification

Answer (score 0):

Use `concatMapEager` (it will eagerly subscribe to both observables and wait for `obsOne` to complete before emitting `obsTwo` items):

```
Observable<User> doit =
  Observable
    .concatEager(
        obsOne.cast(User.class)
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
        obsTwo.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
    .doOnNext(user -> doSomething(user));
```

Note that the `cast` operator adds a little bit of overhead and if you wanted to avoid it you can do this:

```
Observable<User> doit =
  Observable
    .concatEager(
      (Observable<User>)(Observable<?>) obsOne
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
       obsTwo.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
    .doOnNext(user -> doSomething(user));
```